# How to calculate Task due date as last working day of a current month

Tags: apex

I want to update a task due date as last working day of the current month for only one recordtype using apex class. It should exclude the weekends and holidays.

Comment: What did you try so far.

Comment: In line with Reshma's comment, please remember that this site isn't a code-writing service. If anything, I'd say we're a mix of platform knowledge and code review. That aside, I'm afraid that you'll find calculating business days is not a trivial matter. Is there the possibility of relaxing the date requirement? Even if a task is due on a weekend/holiday, people would still need to complete it beforehand (unless they want to be overdue). If so, programmatically obtaining the first day of the next month, and subtracting one day would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend you make use of the [Business Hours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_businesshours.htm) used within the environment. Here is a simple piece of apex that you can use to get the last working day of a month.

```
Date selectedDate =  Date.today().addMonths(11);
Date lastDate = selectedDate.toStartOfMonth().addDays(Date.daysInMonth(selectedDate.year(), selectedDate.month()) - 1);

BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
Boolean isWithin = BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, lastDate);
```

Using this Boolean value, when false you can subtract 1 day from the lastDate until we receive a true value stating the date found is a business day.

```
while (!BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, lastDate)){
    lastDate = lastDate.addDays(-1);
}
```

Now that you have the correct date you can work with RecordTypes as you have stated in your question and also the setting of ActivityDate on Task.

When you are posting a question in future make sure to add your attempted code so people can assist you rather than write the logic for you.

Comment: But iam getting error as 'Apex trigger Tasktrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: Tasktrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded' when save the record